# SciPy rootfinding algorithm 'gives up' too fast

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

Is there any way to force *'hybr'* method of scipy.optimize *'root'* to keep working even after it finds that convergence its too slow? In my problem, the solver nearly reaches desired precision, but right before it, the algorithm terminates because of slow convergence... Is it possible to make 'hybr' more 'self-confident'?

I use the root-finding algorithm *root* from scipy.optimize module to solve a system of two algebraic, non-linear equations. Since the equations have to be solved many times for various parameter values it is important to find a numerical method that would be most stable for this problem.

I have compared the performance of all the methods provided by scipy.optimize module. To visualize their performance I have used the following procedure:

1. The algebraic equations were rearranged so that they have zero on the R.H.S.
2. Then, at each step made by the algorithm, the sum of the L.H.S. squared of all the equations was computed and printed.

In my case, the most efficient method is the default *"hybr"*. Other build-in methods either do not converge at all or are significantly slower. Unfortunately, in some cases the desired method gives up too fast. Lowering the precision and/or providing additional options to the functions did not help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.